# Overloading operator == and hashCode on classes not marked @immutable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the warning: Avoid overloading operator == and hashCode on classes not marked `@immutable`.

Indeed, the class has two fields which are not final, however, these are not part of the operator overloading, neither the hashCode method.

Can I ignore this warning in this case?

This is a simple dummy example, not that the id won't be changed.

```
class SimpleNotMutableClass {
   final String id;
   final int count;
   final String name;

   String? imageUrl;

   SimpleNotMutableClass({
      required this.id,
      required this.count,
      required this.name,
   });

   @override
   bool operator ==(Object other) => identical(this, other) || other is SimpleNotMutableClass && id == other.id;

   @override
   int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring this warning is "safe". You shouldn't have issues.

Comment: Thank you, and if you'll add this as an answer, I'll accept it.